# Export SSRS 2005 report to Excel 2007

Tags: export, office-2007, export-to-excel, reportingservices-2005

Is there any way to export a SSRS 2005 report to Excel 2007 (.xlsx) instead of Excel 2003 (.xls)?

Comment: SSRS 2005 was written before Excel 2007 existed, why would you think it would convert to Excel 2007? Excel 2007 easily reads older Excel files though.

Comment: I'm asking because I don't know everything. :) ... Maybe there is some work around in existence that could help. Of course Excel 2007 can open older Excel files; but SSRS 2005 is bound by limitations of older versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that a half year has passed, however this question returns quite often and I hope someone will find my answer usefull.

Native output for SSRS 2005 is usually reffered as the WebForm and this is basically what SSRS is suppose to produce. The thing is that often users wants to have the report in other form and thats why exporting (translation) has been added. The problem here is that it isnt generating output directly to desired form, but it creates a webform that is beeing processed and translated to another format (thus additional issues/limitations).

While the official answer from the MS representatives is that you need to have MS SQL 2012 (which I can understand - as there's a matter of official support, company internal policy  etc.) there is a number of ways allowing us to archive that goal.

It mostly depends on a reason why you want to have it in xslx.
Most often it is just because of (big table in report) xls rows/colums limitations.

What can you do?

1. Get 3rd party plugin 
   (someone already seen this as a potential benefit - there are example links in article at URL 1
2. Configure your own defined renderer - described at URL 2, but requires you to have translation engine
3. Use VBA in Excel 2007 file to import data (as xls or csv) and save it as you like it.
4. Use workaround - make your tables the way they fit into Excel 2003 restrictions.
   eg. in case of too many rows (described at URL 3):

> On the table properties, go to the Groups tab and add a new group. In the Group on area enter: =Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/60000) and check the Page Break at End box.

URL 1 - social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9d8cd766-ff78-490f-8a5d-bb4a0debdfc1/export-ssrs-2005-report-to-excel-2007

URL 2 - www.traviata.eu/blogs/technical/?p=435

URL 3 - www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic554766-150-1.aspx